# Can someone help me to Insert multiple pictures on laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel so tried to insert informations to table on mysql used migrate for Images table but when i insert Multiple pictures it's returns with this error :

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

If you guys have experience to this feel free to advise thanks.

Here is Input code of multiple pictures:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple>
```

Here is Controller code

```
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Testing\MimeType;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Images;
public function insert (Request $Request){
      $name = $Request->input('name');
$price = $Request->input('price');
$qty = $Request->input('qty');
$description = $Request->input('description');
$email = $Request->input('email');
$utas = $Request->input('utas');
$uruu = $Request->input('uruu');
$garage = $Request->input('garage');
$duureg = $Request->input('duureg');
$tagt = $Request->input('tagt');
$bairshil = $Request->input('bairshil');
$talbai = $Request->input('talbai');
$haalga = $Request->input('haalga');
$tsonh = $Request->input('tsonh');
$shal = $Request->input('shal');
$ttsonh = $Request->input('ttsonh');
$bdawhar = $Request->input('bdawhar');
$ashigon = $Request->input('ashig');
$lizing = $Request->input('lizing');
$bairlal = $Request->input('bairlal');
$hereg = $Request->input('hereg');
$zahi = $Request->input('zahi');
$file='';
$file_tmp='';
$location="uploads/";
$data='';
 foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$val)
{
 $file=$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
 $file_tmp=$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$location.$file);
 $data .=$file." ";
 }
    DB::table('laravel_products')
                 ->insert( array(
                     'name' => $name,
                     'price' => $price,
                     'qty' => $qty,
                     'description' => $description,
                     'uruu' => $uruu,
                     'garage' => $garage,
                     'duureg' => $duureg,
                     'tagt' => $tagt,
                     'talbai' => $talbai,
                     'haalga' => $haalga,
                     'tsonh' => $tsonh,
                     'shal' => $shal,
                     'tsonhtoo' => $ttsonh,
                     'hdawhar' => $bdawhar,
                     'lizing' => $lizing,
                     'utas' => $utas,
                     'email' => $email,
                     'hereg' => $hereg,
                     'bairshil' => $bairshil,
                     'bairlal' => $bairlal,
                     'ashig' => $ashigon,
                     'zahi' => $zahi,
                     'image' => $data
                     )
                 );
                $lastInsertedID = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
                $images = $Request->input('file');
      foreach ($images as $image){
            $image_new_name = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('uploads',$image_new_name);
            $post = new Images;
            $post->product_id = $lastInsertedID;
            $post->image = 'uploads/' . $image_new_name;
            $post->save();
        }
         return view('createproduct');
}
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the input names are not match. Can you try `$_FILES['file']`?

Your code looks like CI, not Laravel :))

Comment: Which of these lines throws that error? What have you tried to resolve it? Also, should one really use `move_uploaded_file` within Laravel?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try searching before posting a new question - I searched for "*laravel multiple file upload*" and found many answers here already.

Answer (score 0):

I do like this. Hope this could be helpful for you.

```
   $image1 = $request->image1; // keep image in variable
   $image2 = $request->image2; // keep image in variable
   $data = array(); // declare a array type variable

       if(!empty($image1)) //check image1 is empty or not
            {
                $image1_name=uniqid().date('dmYhis'); // set image name
                $image1_upload_path='backend/product_images/'; // set upload path
                $ext6=strtolower($image1->getClientOriginalExtension()); //get extension
                $image1_full_name=$image1_name.'.'.$ext6; // set image name with extension
                $image1_url=$image1_upload_path.$image1_full_name; // keep image upload url to a variable
                $success=$image1->move($image1_upload_path,$image1_full_name); // move to upload folder
                $data['image1']=$image1_url; // finaly store image link to database
            }



            if(!empty($image2)) //check image2 is empty or not
            {
                $image2_name=uniqid().date('dmYhis'); // set image name
                $image2_upload_path='backend/product_images/';  // set upload path
                $ext6=strtolower($image1->getClientOriginalExtension()); //get extension
                $image2_full_name=$image2_name.'.'.$ext6; // set image name with extension
                $image2_url=$image2_upload_path.$image2_full_name; // keep image upload url to a variable
                $success=$image2->move($image2_upload_path,$image2_full_name); // move to upload folder
                $data['image2']=$image2_url; // finaly store image link to database
            }
            $store = Product::create($data); // store data to database with Product model
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: I have edited codes with comments for explaining. please check it.

Comment: or you can use Laravel Intervention to upload images. Official website http://image.intervention.io/ Read Documentation or watch tutorial videos about laravel intervention on youtube. Hope this will be helpful.